# What is the largest/smallest fixed point number than can be represented in 2n bits?

Tags: binary, bit, fixed-point

More specifically **a binary number in 2n bits with n bits of integer (including one bit of sign) and n bits of fraction.**

What would be the smallest and largest, positive, non-zero number we could represent?

I know how to deal with integer but not sure about the fractions.

Comment: This is called [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) representation. It is a simpler alternative to the more common [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), sometimes used on machines that lack floating point instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical binary fixed-point representation is an integer scaled by a constant power of two so the factors involved are

1. the range of the integer and
2. the scale of the fixed-point type.

Given a two's complement integer with a sign bit and `2n-1` digits, the range of positive numbers is `[1..(2^(2n-1))-1]` and the scale is `2^-n`. So the minimum and maximum positive fixed-point values are `[1*2^-n..((2^(2n-1))-1)*2^-n]`.

For example, [C](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info)'s [`int16_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) type has 15 digits so its range is `[1..(2^15)-1]` or `[1..32767]`. Here, `n` is `8` making the scale `2^-8` or `1/256`. So the scaled range is `[1/256..32767/256]` or `[0.00390625..127.99609375]`. You can use this [C++ program](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G1xlz2phblCX39mt) to calculate the range for different values of `n` using [CNL](https://github.com/johnmcfarlane/cnl).

Comment: Now that's what I call a complete answer. I didn't know about CNL but it will be super useful, thank you very much John.

Comment: Where is the this formula comes from? @JohnMcFarlane,

Comment: This is derived from the limits imposed by two's complement integer representation, combined with the scaling effect I mentioned.